# Looking for sets with lots of printed parts or other special parts to use as components for my city

Tags: piece-information, building, sets, city, customization

I'm thinking about building an early 20th century ('30s / '40s) European city, using both complete sets and parts of sets as resources

I'm looking for pieces that add detail to this city, both outside (streets & parks) & inside the buildings... from sofas & benches to kitchen sinks & traffic signs.

I don't really like using stickers and I'd like to avoid them altogether, but I do love printed pieces.

So I wonder... Can some of you folks recommend some sets that have lots of printed parts or other special parts that could help me add detail to my city?

I would prefer sets that haven't been discontinued. However, feel free to recommend discontinued sets if you think they're a great match for me needs.

Comment: It would probably be better and cheaper to buy printed parts from bricklink because of the below answer.

Comment: What kind of print do you have in mind? Wall textures, paintings? In Bricklink, the key word 'pattern' will show all printed parts.

Comment: @Aziraphale : I'm thinking of newspapers, store signs, street signs, book covers, etc. Anything that could add more life and fits in in a 1940s setting would do.

Comment: @TechnicTechnician : Bricklink is definitely an option, especially for rare pieces. However, ordering from Bricklink can be pretty cumbersome & expensive. So, for the less rare parts, I'd rather but them as part of a set.

Answer (score 3):

All of the decorations in the LEGO Juniors (now called LEGO 4+) sets are printed, and they tend to have a lot of nice decorations. Decorated parts in the LEGO Ideas sets are also almost always printed, but double check this because at least some of the sets also have stickers.

There is not one set which is going to be full of printed parts, and sets with printed parts tend to be more expensive when it comes to price per piece. If you are looking for a large quantity of specific printed elements, you are better off to just order exactly what you want from BrickLink, the online LEGO marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

Lego has somewhat recently started a theme called Xtras, if case you weren't aware. They have a variety of odds & ends great for detailing builds. They do have some printed tiles in a few of the packs, but probably not quite the variety you're after.  If you can't find the printed elements needed for your build elsewhere, you might try the 853921 sticker pack as a last resort.

[image]

[image]